# ObjectNode returned with unknown values

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` in my java-rest to return a simple value:

```
@POST
@Path ("/JsonApi")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public ObjectNode postEmployee(JSONObject jsonObject)throws Exception{
    String onlineUrl = MatafConfig.getConfigParam(request,
            m_CONFIG_REDIRECT);
    if(m_mapper == null)
        m_mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode jNode = m_mapper.createObjectNode();
    jNode.put("url", onlineUrl); // debug shows {"url": "/mySite"}

    //return url


    return jNode;
}
```

The value in `jNode` is as expected `{"url": "/mySite"}` but on the client side it shows other json -

`{"nodeType":"OBJECT","valueNode":false,"containerNode":true,"missingNode":false,"array":false,"object":true,"pojo":false,"number":false,"integralNumber":false,"floatingPointNumber":false,"short":false,"int":false,"long":false,"float":false,"double":false,"bigDecimal":false,"bigInteger":false,"textual":false,"boolean":false,"null":false,"binary":false}`

I have no idea about this json, I think it is some default object from `jax-rs` maybe.

More details: java 8, jackson 2.6, using WebSphere 8.5 default `jax-rs` libs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are passing ObjectNode as a return param, Jackson deserializes ObjectNode not it's content.
So, instead of returning ObjectNode, try to create the class, for example, "Url" and return it.
Here is the sample of the class:

```
public class Url {

   private String url;

   public Url(final String url) {
       this.url = url;
   }

   public String getUrl() {
       return url;
   }
}
```

When you return it, it will be automatically converted to JSON representation.